# How to aggregate when there are missing time series data combination

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, missing-data

I have a dataset look like that:

[image]

I want to aggregate data by Date, the result should look like:

[image]

I wrote function "aggregation":

```
## Subset data
seller <- c ("S1", "S2","S3","S4", "S5")
buyer <- c("B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5")
ss <- df[seller, buyer]
```

However, as there is some combination of Seller-Buyer-Food not exist (e.g. Seller S1 and Buyer B3 have no transaction), so R gave me the error:
 `Error in`[.default`(x1, , 1:5) : subscript out of bounds`

Could someone help me how to tell R to continue the "aggregation" function even when the is no transaction between seller-buyer.
I appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could do that with `tidyr` and `spread`:

```
Date <- as.character(Sys.Date()+0:4)
seller <- c ("S1", "S2","S3","S4", "S5")
buyer <- c("B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5")
Food <- c("Coconut","Banana","Peach","Peach","Apple")

df <- data.frame(cbind(Date,seller,buyer,Food),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(tidyr)
df2 <- df%>%
group_by(Date,seller,buyer)%>%
mutate(count=n())%>%
spread(Food,count)
df2[is.na(df2)] <- 0
df2

Source: local data frame [5 x 7]
Groups: Date, seller, buyer [5]

        Date seller buyer Apple Banana Coconut Peach
*      <chr>  <chr> <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 2017-04-18     S1    B1     0      0       1     0
2 2017-04-19     S2    B2     0      1       0     0
3 2017-04-20     S3    B3     0      0       0     1
4 2017-04-21     S4    B4     0      0       0     1
5 2017-04-22     S5    B5     1      0       0     0
```

**EDIT** To account for duplicates, add a `summarise` step. The data set has been modified so that S1, B1, Banana and same date happen.

```
Date <- as.character(Sys.Date()+c(0,0,1,2,3))
seller <- c ("S1", "S1","S3","S4", "S5")
buyer <- c("B1", "B1", "B3", "B4", "B5")
Food <- c("Banana","Banana","Peach","Peach","Apple")

df <- data.frame(cbind(Date,seller,buyer,Food),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(tidyr)
df2 <- df%>%
group_by(Date,seller,buyer,Food)%>%
summarise(count=n())%>%
spread(Food,count)

df2[is.na(df2)] <- 0
df2

        Date seller buyer Apple Banana Peach
*      <chr>  <chr> <chr> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 2017-04-19     S1    B1     0      2     0
2 2017-04-20     S3    B3     0      0     1
3 2017-04-21     S4    B4     0      0     1
4 2017-04-22     S5    B5     1      0     0
```

Comment: Thank you! But The "df" you used is the dataframe you generated, not the subset data "ss" as I made from the full dataset

Comment: @CPA It's because I overwrite my original df. I edited my answer. `df` is now the original data. `df2` is the final one

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I meant the first "df" you created. It only generated 5 rows for 5 sellers, buyers, and food. Can you show me how to link the df to the subset data I have, which I named as "ss" in my codes ("ss" was subset from a big dataset, I also named as "df" in my codes, which include thousands sellers and buyers, but I only want several specific sellers and buyers)

Comment: update: I successfully linked to my dataset. However, R gave me Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows as there are many duplicated transaction (e.g. S1-B1-Banana transaction can happen several times per day, resulting in several similar rows). And the "Date" keeps be generated based on current date instead of the date in my dataset. Any suggestions?

Comment: @P Lapointe The codes run great. But only for single Seller-Buyer-Food transaction per day. However, when Seller-Buyer have some transactions per day, the computation is not correct. For example, if S1 sell Banana to B1 two times on Jan 1 2017, the result comes up with 4 transactions instead of 2. I guess the reason is from "summarise(count=sum(count)) " but don't know to solve that. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

The `dcast()` function from the `reshape2` or `data.table` packages will reshape your data from long to wide format conveniently in a one-liner:

```
data.table::dcast(ss, ... ~ Food, value.var = "Food", fill = 0L, fun = length)
#        Date seller buyer Apple Banana Coconut Peach
#1 2017-01-01     S1    B1     0      0       1     0
#2 2017-01-01     S2    B1     0      1       0     0
#3 2017-01-02     S2    B3     0      0       0     1
#4 2017-01-03     S3    B1     0      0       0     1
#5 2017-01-03     S3    B2     1      0       0     0
#6 2017-01-03     S4    B3     0      0       1     0
```

This will also work for duplicate entries as in the sample data of the edit to the [`dplyr` / `tidyr` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43483552/3817004).

#### Benchmark results

Even for a data.frame `ss` with only 6 rows, `dcast()` is more than twice as fast as the `dplyr` / `tidyr` solution:

```
Unit: milliseconds
   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 tidyr2 4.765453 4.911954 5.140440 5.011259 5.163234 6.853099   100
  dcast 1.934349 2.004580 2.102577 2.061972 2.122196 3.507352   100
```

#### Benchmark code

```
Date <- as.Date("2017-01-01") + c(0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L)
seller <- c ("S1", "S2", "S2", "S3","S3", "S4")
buyer <- c("B1", "B1", "B3", "B1", "B2", "B3")
Food <- c("Coconut", "Banana", "Peach", "Peach", "Apple", "Coconut")
ss <- data.frame(Date, seller, buyer, Food, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(magrittr)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  tidyr2 = {
    df2 <- ss%>%
      dplyr::group_by(Date,seller,buyer)%>%
      dplyr::mutate(count=n())%>%
      dplyr::group_by(Date,seller,buyer,Food)  %>%
      dplyr::summarise(count=sum(count))  %>%
      tidyr::spread(Food,count)
    df2[is.na(df2)] <- 0
    df2
  },
  dcast = {
    data.table::dcast(ss, ... ~ Food, value.var = "Food", fill = 0L, fun = length)
  }
)
```